# Quick Regex Matches Question

Tags: regex, vb.net, parsing

(Yes I am using regex to parse HTML, its the only solution I know)

Im having trouble creating the regex for the below piece of code, there are about 10 matches per page.

```
<A href="viewmessage.aspx?message_id=1906782643&Guid=25851900&SID=k1fprtq2dbadgshntng1w3qb" style="text-decoration:underline">Inner Text</A>
```

this is the regex ive been trying

below is the code I usually use to get a match collection

```
Private Function Extract(ByVal source As String) As String()
        Dim mc As MatchCollection
        Dim i As Integer
        mc = Regex.Matches(source, _
"<A href=" & Chr(34) & "viewmessage.aspx?message_id *.</A>")
        Dim results(mc.Count - 1) As String
        For i = 0 To results.Length - 1
            results(i) = mc(i).Value
        Next
        Return results
    End Function

Dim str1 As String()
        Dim str2 As String
        Dim results As New StringBuilder
        str1 = Extract(result)
        For Each str2 In str1
            results.Append(str2 & vbNewLine)
        Next

RTBlinks.Text = results.ToString
```

Could anyone point out what im doing wrong ? I have spent a few hours trying different things.

I try to program mainly as a hobby, so apologies if ive made any glaring errors.

Comment: Even as a hobbyist, I think you will find it more rewarding to learn how to integrate the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) with your project and figure out its syntax for traversing the DOM rather than fighting the regex demons.

Answer (score 2):

You've got `*.` where you'd need `.*`. Right now, the quantifier `*` is applied to the space before it, and the dot matches exactly one character. Switch the two, remove the space (it matters, and there is no space in your test string at this point) and try again.

Be aware that `.*` matches greedily, i. e. as many characters as possible (except newlines). So if you have no more than one `<A>` tag per line, it should still work. A bit safer would be `.*?` instead, making the dot match as few characters as possible; even safer `[^<]*` which would match anything except opening angle brackets, making sure we don't cross tag boundaries.

However, all of those measures fail in certain, not uncommon situations (think comments, attribute strings, nested tags, invalid markup) which is why you should let regexes loose on markup languages only if you can exactly control your inputs and know your limitations.

Also, I think that in VB.NET you can escape quotes inside a string by doubling it, so you can simply write

```
"<A href=""viewmessage.aspx?message_id=.*?</A>"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with my question, learned some handy things.